# Loop through Resource attributes in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a cron job that does three things. Every Minute I check to see if there are any new notifications to be sent at the current time. Every day I change the current day on the calendar to today. Every hour I change the current hour to the current hour. My problem is within my Month model I cannot loop over my days to see if there are any notifications. I've debugged and found I do call the method but when it comes to accessing the attributes on the Month itself nothing happens. Calling the self.send_fridays_notifications does not access the months days and the notification within each days notifications, it never even gets into the loop. Any reasons why? In the controller I can use an instance variable like @month.fridays.each do |friday| and it works. Using self screws up the function.

**month.rb**

```
class Month < ActiveRecord::Base
def self.send_fridays_notifications
    self.fridays.each do |friday|
        friday.notifications.each do |notification|
            if notification.time == time.hour
                p "Sending", notification
            end
         end
     end
end
```

Comment: A few clarifying questions: what does the `fridays` method return? Is that a scope on the `Month` model? Does it return instances of `Month`? Also, what is the variable `t` in your snippet above? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: So a month has many Fridays, and a Friday has many notifications. Fridays should return a friday object with many notifications. Each notification in the fridays notifications returns an object with the target_user, the message, and the notification time. t.hour was the Current Times hour. I recently changed it to Time.hour